# acts-as-taggable-on tagged_with order('random()')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to use act-as-taggable-on's `tagged_with` method with a `random()` order like this,

```
Dvd.tagged_with(@site.tag, wild: true, any: true).order('RANDOM()').limit(20)
```

But I'm getting the following error,

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY     expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ... OR dvds_taggings_c684506.tag_id = 3786) ORDER BY RANDOM() L...
                                                         ^
: SELECT  DISTINCT dvds.* FROM "dvds" JOIN taggings dvds_taggings_c684506  ON     dvds_taggings_c684506.taggable_id = "dvds".id AND dvds_taggings_c684506.taggable_type = 'Dvd' WHERE (dvds_taggings_c684506.tag_id = 72 OR dvds_taggings_c684506.tag_id = 2823 OR dvds_taggings_c684506.tag_id = 3786) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 20
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Postgres - but from a search - it looks like the DISTINCT clause that is getting kicked out from act_as_taggable-on's `tagged_with` is throwing a kink into things (at least according to [this pgsql thread](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2010-10/msg00004.php)

Following along from that post, you could probably construct this as a subquery using AREL - something like (I haven't ran this in a console anywhere, but this may give you a direction to pursue)

```
class Dvd < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.random_list(limit = 20)
    with_scope do
      subquery = self.tagged_with(@site.tag, wild: true, any: true).pluck(:id)
      self.where("ID IN(#{subquery.to_sql})").order("RANDOM()").limit(limit)
    end
  end

end
```

It's probably not all that efficient, but my understanding that ORDER BY RANDOM() isn't either (all the data that I've ever tried to get a random set from was so small I could just load all of it, and use Array#shuffle to let ruby give me a random list - I doubt your Dvd set is small enough to do that - except for relatively unique tags).

Comment: I'm not surprised :-) - it was a copy and paste from code I have and a wild-stab at a possibility - sorry about that.  I'd have to bring up a sample project to eyeball it ( the pluck(:id) is for sure going to get confused between the Dvd table and the tags and needs to be table specific ). I was also assuming that act_as_taggable_on returns a scope and it looked it did from a glance.  If I get some time I'll see if I can make it work. The gist is that that forum post is indicating that a subquery is needed - and AREL can help make that easy to construct.